# Error vue : vue: command not found

Tags: windows, vue.js, cmd, console, nuxt.js

I'm trying to install a standard vue template, but I get an error `vue: command not found`.

I followed the following steps:

1. `npm install vue`
2. `npm install -g @vue/cli`
3. `vue init nuxt-community/starter-templete`

What are the ways to solve the problem?

Comment: You need to run `npm install -g vue-cli`

Comment: @SimonHyll Please, look at point 2. I did it.

Comment: Then all I can think of is that your PATH might be incorrect. Try adding `%AppData%\Roaming\npm` to your environment PATH variable.

Comment: @SimonHyll It helped, only I did it a long time ago, because the question was asked a long time ago). But anyway, thanks